# How to change physical order of mysql table?

Tags: mysql, database, io

I'm trying to get an idea of what's a proper way to arrange data with a predefined order, it may be easier to explain using this example:

Say there's a table posts with userid column, it gets filled as posts are sent with autoincrement primary id. The application needs to get the last 300 posts from a single user, aggregate them and display the result. If there's a lot of users and posts, it may occur that all 300 posts from this user are in different places of disk, there's not enough ram to cache the database files, and to serve one request, mysql needs to do 300 io ops, so with a hdd able to do 150 iops, that request would require 2 seconds and a second concurrent user will need to wait a lot.

If my understanding is correct, having table ordered by userid would make the data placed nearby on disk and mysql would be able to read all the data in 1-ish io request, making the performance drastically better? So how do I make mysql place the rows in a predefined physical order if I know how that data will be used in advance? How is this problem solved in general?

I'd like to keep using autoincrement, since there are other writable mysql servers and it's convenient to use autoincrement offset and increment.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I do not think that you get to decide where is data stored on disk. I don't even think that MySQL decides where data is stored on disk, since disk can be spanned, raid, network, etc. In my opinion OS and kernel are in charge of that. Closest you can get to controlling what get stored and how, is indexing. More about that at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: @D.Kasipovic: indexing doesn't control *how* it gets stored. it's just an extra index file.

Comment: Yes, of course, but it is kind of control on mysql regards the data, sort of an explanation of the data in the table, and as I said it's the closest to what he said imho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, some theoretical limitations:

Imagine that the data is physically ordered. Now, what happens if a user posts another message/comment? To keep ordering, it has to be next to his posts. This means that either

- you have to shift all the posts next to it - impossible as your question clearly assumes there's a *lot* of data
- you need holes in the file to allow inserting - but how much space should you keep? you cannot know in advance.
- you store it in "chuncks". you allocate a couple of disk blocks for each user, once it gets filled, you allocate a new chunk. now you only need seeks for the chunks and not for each post. this method doesn't alter the asymptotic complexity of disk seeks, but decreasing it to 1/10 or 1/100 is still a big win. not sure if any RDBMs does this.
- you store it somewhere else, and later you fix the ordering - essentially you're doing a disk defragmentation. Ideally the RDBMs will do this for you - but in practice most won't. You can do it manually in a daily(?) batch process but it's a ridiculously complex task (to do it right) so unless you're in a huge company which has the capacity to do this, it isn't feasible.

To make the situation a lot worse, as @D.Kasipovic mentioned in the comments, you don't even know where a MySQL file is stored on a physical disk. It can be already fragmented. Some RDBM systems allow direct disk access (I heard Oracle and SQL Server can do this), but I don't know whether they support physical ordering of the records.

So what can you do?

- Use SSD. It doesn't seek so it can do *a lot* of iops. Problem solved.
- If you do sharding, shard by user. You'll only stress a single DB server (or its slaves) with the query.
- If you know the number of posts per user has a sane limit, you can store all the posts of a user in a single row. Clearly this is a quite ugly hack on an RDBMs, but with some noSQL solutions it can do the job.

<sub>Note: I used all of these methods (sometimes even on the same system) and they worked well. SSD is an easy win if you need a quick solution - and remember, unless you scale big, hardware is cheaper than developer wages.</sub>

Comment: +1 for the nosql or alike solution. In fact, if posts are not changed too often (multiple times per second), you can just have the last 300 posts cached somewhere on disk (in json, or array, or even another mysql table), and use that instead of doing select every time.

Comment: Is defragmentation what myisam does with `alter table test order by ind`? If so, may be it better to simply use myisam as a db engine?

Comment: @fluffy: yes, that's defragmentation. measure how long it takes (with the volume of data and inserts you expect to handle) because it does write lock. I assume it's slow so you probably have to do it on a slave and then reconnect to master... it quickly gets a lot more complicated than it sounds.